# How to add new row to a related table (with Relationship Class) in ArcGIS Pro using Pro attribute table

Tags: arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, relationship-class

I have a FC called `Schools.SDE.Schools` and a Table called `Schools.SDE.Maintenance` and
there is a Relationship class between them called `Schools.SDE.Schools_Maintenance`

[image]

Now using the `Attribute Pane` [image] I am able to edit the selected `Schools.SDE.Schools` feature

[image]

but I need to add new Maintenance into `Schools.SDE.Maintenance` related into selected feature using the `Attribute Pane` [image] and as you can see the pane is not showing any option to add new row (Maintenance) into `Schools.SDE.Maintenance`

[image]

How can I achieve this in ArcGIS Pro?